# Javascript overload functions detect by visual studio code intellisense

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

How to write a javascript overload function that can be detected by visual studio code intellisense and also how to document the same.

For example jasmine's it() function is showed as below.

function it(expectation: string, assertion?: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void **(+1 overload)**

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine doesn't actually have two methods defined (one overloading the other). The reason you see that in your IDE is because the typing file has two versions declared for the different usage available. For example, here is how an [older version of DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a484c8887264c7a4fcd42487d0ae865ff2febd53/types/jasmine/v1/index.d.ts#L11-L12) had the `it()` function set up:

```
// Type definitions for Jasmine 1.3
// ...

declare function it(expectation: string, assertion: () => void): void;
declare function it(expectation: string, assertion: (done: (err?: any) => void) => void): void;
```

For reference, here is the relevant code in that version of Jasmine to show that there is only one function handling these two use cases:

**[base.js (lines 485-501)](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/fd914337925a1e2729e2583a1023b2293d54ca55/src/core/base.js#L485-L501)**

```
/**
 * Creates a Jasmine spec that will be added to the current suite.
 *
 * // TODO: pending tests
 *
 * @example
 * it('should be true', function() {
 *   expect(true).toEqual(true);
 * });
 *
 * @param {String} desc description of this specification
 * @param {Function} func defines the preconditions and expectations of the spec
 */
var it = function(desc, func) {
  return jasmine.getEnv().it(desc, func);
};
if (isCommonJS) exports.it = it;
```

**[Env.js (lines 151-161)](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/fd914337925a1e2729e2583a1023b2293d54ca55/src/core/Env.js#L151-L161)**

```
jasmine.Env.prototype.it = function(description, func) {
  var spec = new jasmine.Spec(this, this.currentSuite, description);
  this.currentSuite.add(spec);
  this.currentSpec = spec;

  if (func) {
    spec.runs(func);
  }

  return spec;
};
```

Comment: I need to add a method in an object like below
add(x, y, z? = 0) 
How can I show it as a overload function which can take 2 parameters as well as 3 parameters ?
Do I need to use type definitions?

Comment: @saianudeep Why do you need that? Your function specification shows that very thing already.